# Trying to pip install but get ```TypeError: 'Version' object is not subscriptable```

Tags: python, pip, package

I'm on ubuntu and tried to install tardis by using:

```
pip install tardis-sn
```

but the output i got was:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting tardis-sn
  Using cached tardis-sn-1.0.1.tar.gz (1.1 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [14 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-install-4mc4s8kc/tardis-sn_98dc7e578b0a49ada4013a6ad17ba118/setup.py", line 8, in <module>
          import ah_bootstrap
        File "/tmp/pip-install-4mc4s8kc/tardis-sn_98dc7e578b0a49ada4013a6ad17ba118/ah_bootstrap.py", line 530, in <module>
          _main()
        File "/tmp/pip-install-4mc4s8kc/tardis-sn_98dc7e578b0a49ada4013a6ad17ba118/ah_bootstrap.py", line 527, in _main
          use_astropy_helpers(**kwargs)
        File "/tmp/pip-install-4mc4s8kc/tardis-sn_98dc7e578b0a49ada4013a6ad17ba118/ah_bootstrap.py", line 198, in use_astropy_helpers
          upgrade = _do_upgrade(dist, index_url)
        File "/tmp/pip-install-4mc4s8kc/tardis-sn_98dc7e578b0a49ada4013a6ad17ba118/ah_bootstrap.py", line 285, in _do_upgrade
          major, minor = (int(part) for part in dist.parsed_version[:2])
      TypeError: 'Version' object is not subscriptable
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Please help me get rid of this error

I have tried using

```
pip install tardis-sn --use-deprecated=legacy-resolver
```

but the output i got was still the same

Comment: The package at PyPI seems to be outdated; [last release](https://pypi.org/project/tardis-sn/1.0.1/) was in 2015. The [installation docs](https://tardis-sn.github.io/tardis/installation.html) say "*TARDIS packages and dependencies are distributed only through the conda package management system, therefore installation requires Anaconda or Miniconda to be installed on your system.*"

Comment: I managed to try to install it by using conda but then I got an error but i solved the error using ```mamba install``` instead of conda install. You can find everything about mamba here https://mamba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/mamba.html . Thank you phd!